# How to use mindepth and maxdepth in `or` alternative in File::Find::Rule?

Tags: perl

I have the following folder structure (as a minimal example):

```
dir
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── c.txt
│   │   └── d.txt
│   └── c
│       └── q.txt
├── b
│   ├── bb.txt
│   └── d
│       └── dd.txt
└── q.txt
```

I want to find all `.txt` files but exclude everything in `dir/b` from the search using [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) (I know I could do this easily using [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) but that would require a substantial refactoring of my code).

I tried the following:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = 'dir';
my @files = File::Find::Rule->or(
    File::Find::Rule->directory->mindepth(1)->maxdepth(1)
                    ->name( 'b' )->prune->discard,
    File::Find::Rule->name('*.txt'),
)->in( $dir );
say for @files;
```

**Output**:

```
dir/q.txt
dir/a/c/q.txt
```

**Expected output**:

```
dir/q.txt
dir/a/b/d.txt
dir/a/b/c.txt
dir/a/c/q.txt
```

Seems like `maxdepth()` and `mindepth()` are not working inside the `or()` function.

Comment: looks like name(b) is a regex and is matching /b/ in your expected list.

Comment: @jwal Yes it looks like, but if you change the name of `dir/a/b` to `dir/a/bb` you will get matches from `dir/a/bb` also. So `name('b')` is not discarding `bb` in the first alternative. Which indicates that `name('b')` is not a regex, but `name(qr/b/)` would be a regex according to the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like with the `find` command-line tool, `maxdepth` doesn't limit where a match can occur; it limits the actual traversal.

> `maxdepth( $level )`
>
> Descend at most `$level` (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the starting point.

Just like the `find` command-line tool, `mindepth` prevents all tests from being performed before a certain depth.

> `mindepth( $level )`
>
> Do not apply any tests at levels less than `$level` (a non-negative integer).

Given what they do, they affect the entire search. As such, it's no surprise the `mindepth` and `maxdepth` from the outer rule object is the one used and the others are ignored.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

The same solution that applies to the `find` command-line tool can be used here.

`find`:

```
$ find dir -wholename dir/b -prune -o -name '*.txt' -print
dir/a/b/c.txt
dir/a/b/d.txt
dir/a/c/q.txt
dir/q.txt
```

File::Find::Rule:

```
$ perl -MFile::Find::Rule -e'
   my ($dir) = @ARGV;
   CORE::say for
      File::Find::Rule
         ->or(
            File::Find::Rule->exec(sub { $_[2] eq "$dir/b" })->prune->discard,
            File::Find::Rule->name("*.txt"),
         )
         ->in($dir);
' dir
dir/q.txt
dir/a/b/c.txt
dir/a/b/d.txt
dir/a/c/q.txt
```

Another approach would be to use File::Find::Rule to build a list of directories to search, then search those directories with another use of File::Find::Rule. (The Perl equivalent of `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} find {} ...`.)

---

1. The `find` command-line utility handles the misplaced inputs differently.

   ```
   $ find dir -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name b -prune -o -name '*.txt' -print
   find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument (, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

   find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument (, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

   dir/q.txt
   ```