# perl - File::Find::Rule to exclude a single dir only for the top level

Tags: perl, find

I tried the following to exclude the directory 'CVS'

```
my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new;
$rule->or($rule->new->directory->name('CVS')->prune->discard, $rule->new);
```

But however this effectively excludes any CVS directories that live inside the directory tree.

Here is an example :

- source/CVS (should be excluded)
- source/A/CVS (should not be excluded)
- source/B/
- source/C/dog/CVS (should not be excluded)

Comment: See also [How to use mindepth and maxdepth in `or` alternative in File::Find::Rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52672370/2173773)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Perl equivalent of `find dir -wholename dir/CVS -prune -o -print`.

```
say
   for
      File::Find::Rule
         ->or(
            File::Find::Rule->exec(sub { $_[2] eq "$dir/CVS" })->prune->discard,
            File::Find::Rule->new(),
         )
         ->in($dir);
```

Another approach would be to use File::Find::Rule to build a list of directories to search, then search those directories with another use of File::Find::Rule. (The Perl equivalent of `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} find {} ...`.)