# Find::File::Rule exclude sub directories

Tags: perl

I have the following code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my @text = File::Find::Rule->file()
                           ->name('*.txt')
                           ->in('c:\windows','c:\temp');
```

and want only to find all the .txt files under c:\windows and not under c:\windows\ subfoldes like c:\windows\test1 etc.. is it possible to do something like this with `File::Find::Rule`

Comment: See also [How to use mindepth and maxdepth in `or` alternative in File::Find::Rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52672370/2173773)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid recursing through the use of `->maxdepth(1)`.

IIRC, it needs to come before your other filters.